# Chrome new tab event

Tags: events, google-chrome-extension

I want to fire an event when a new tab is created in Chrome. I thought the following would do it, but it seems not. *(beginner)*

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

background.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {alert('hello new tab'});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just missing a closing `)` bracket?

```
...{alert('hello new tab'});
                         ^
```

Because other than that your code works for me.