# Chrome extension to redirect tab to my page

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions and I am having trouble while writing my first extension for chrome. What I am trying to do is detect the new tab action and redirect to a pre-defined(my webpage) url.

I wrote the manifest.json and the background.html but it doesn't seem to work.
I went through the google papers on the functions and how to use them, but there must be something I've missed.

I do not understand quite a few things that I've done in here, for example the content-scripts in manifest.json.

Some help in fixing this would be appreciated.

*EDIT*

[image: Error]

*EDIT2*
Here is the updated code
Now I don't have the background.html file.
manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Tabber",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "MyExtension",
  "background" : {
    "scripts": ["code.js"]
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "code.js"
   },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

code.js

```
<script>
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
            var action_url = "www.xyz.com"
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: action_url });
    }
</script>
```

Now when I open a new tab, I get to see the source of the .js file displayed.
Screenshot:
[image: Output]

Why isn't the script being executed ?

Comment: Please search before you post. Here's the similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743072/chrome-new-tab-event

Comment: read my answer, your need html file, not js.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to over ride a default page, you shoud use html file, not a js file.
And if you just want to over ride a page, you do not need any background page or content script.
Here is the sample code:

menifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Tabber",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "MyExtension",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "my.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

my.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>over ride page</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
</body>
</html>
```

code.js:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
```

Note: you can not write any js in your html file. You need to include js file in html file.

And, you even do not need any js file. just modify the my.html as this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh"content="0;URL=http://www.google.com">
</head>
```

Comment: Bless you for sharing this...  was getting suicidal reading all the (recent-ish) docs on how executeScript no longer works in new tabs... this saved the day.

Answer (score 2):

With the new chrome extensions you should not put any script code in the background page.

> Inline scripts and event handlers disallowed
>
> Due to the use of Content Security Policy, you can no longer use
>    tags that are inline with the HTML content. These must be
>   moved to external JS files. In addition, inline event handlers are
>   also not supported. For example, suppose you had the following code in
>   your extension:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#inline_scripts

> What you should do is move your code to a js file, either set the
>   manifest background property to a js file or have a background page
>   that links to an external js file and put all you js code there...

Try using the background property: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

1)basically add to your manifest a background script (you do not need the background page for your extension right now)

```
background : {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

2) Then add a a background.js to your extension directory and put all your js code there..

Then try again, and see if the extension works :)

3) remove all html from the js file and put just you js in the background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
            var action_url = "www.xyz.com"
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: action_url });
    }
```

Comment: Did that, now I get the content of the .js file displayed when I open a new tab. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: the content? what do you mean?

Comment: Remove the html from the background.js just put the follow in the JS file:

Comment: ?? The javascript code is being displayed in the new tab instead of loading the webpage. There is so html in the .js file. Check the *edit2* in the main post.

Comment: remove all the html and put just the js code in the background page, see the edit I made to the answer?

Comment: I've exactly that code in my "code.js" file. There is no html in that .js file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47108/discussion-between-priyabrata-and-dory-zidon)

Answer (score 1):

Add this guy to your manifest.json file.

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "index.html"
   }
```

with index.html being replaced with your page. This will make it so it will show index.html when you open a new tab instead of the default.

I have an extension that basically does the same thing. Here's my manifest.json that you can use as a reference.

```
{
  "name": "appName",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "index.html"
   },

  "description": "Desc Here",
  "icons": {
    // "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [ {
  "css": ["css/styles.css"],
  "js": [ ],
  "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
  "run_at": "document_start"
  } ],
  "minimum_chrome_version": "18",
  "permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "cookies", "tabs", "notifications" ]

}
```

Comment: Honestly I don't know too much about manifest.json stuff but I do know an extension I just wrote it working like you would want yours, so I've posted it for your reference. You're probably just needing to separate your JS and CSS files like I have and update your content scripts sections.

Comment: its causing the same problems :(

Comment: after few years, this was the answer I was looking for, no one goes through all the documentation right away right, thanks for pointing me in the correct direction @TylerMcGinnis, I wanted to redirect users to my custom web app whenever they creates a new tab, I used `chrome.tabs.onCreated`, but it was inconsistent for the job, so  I used just a one line of js in overriden html.

Comment: Glad 2014 me could help you out @HasinthaAbeykoon!