# Chrome Extension - on extension click, new tab and redirect

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome Extension that on click of the extension icon opens a new tab & redirects to a url.

I've managed to find answers that redirect to a url on every new tab opening or load js but I only want it to execute when the extension icon is clicked.

Here's the broken code:

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "description": "Opens a new tab and redirects",
    "version": "0.2",
    "chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab": "redirect.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

redirect.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh"content="0;URL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
</head>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extensions - Open New Tab when clicking a toolbar icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188384/google-chrome-extensions-open-new-tab-when-clicking-a-toolbar-icon)

Answer (score 1):

**See these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14682627/6525260 ,and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3189335/6525260**

Steps:

1. Have manifest version 2 (`"manifest_version":2,`)
2. Include tabs for permissions
3. Listen for mouse click event on browser action in your background page (Code below)

*(Mouse Click Event)*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('open_page_name.html')}, function(tab) {
        //tab opened
    });
});
```

*(now code if you chose direct url)*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

*(Manifest Permissions)*

```
"permissions":["tabs"],
```

Comment: Thanks Arnav, I poured through those answers and the links the answers refer to but none of it worked. Still getting no response on toolbar icon click. Can't seem to find a single working code example for this.

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21656716/6525260) Replace `_self` with `_blank`