# Chrome Extension - pass parameter to new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a chrome extension that open my website on homepage / new tab. I used the HTML tag `<meta http-equiv..` to redirect the user to my website and it working great.

The problem is that I want to pass parameter (create unique ID for each user) and to attach this parameter to my website URL:

for example: http://www.mywebsite.com/?**user_id=parameter_value_here**

1. where I should create my user id?
2. how I pass it to the new tab html file?

My extension code:

**newTab.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.mywebsite.com/?user_id=value_here" />
    </head>
    <body style="display: none;">

    </body>
</html>
```

**Manifest**

```
{
  "name": "My website name",
  "version": "1.1",
  "description": "website description goes here",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "newTab.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "topSites",
    "chrome://favicon/"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions":[
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*", 
    "management", 
    "storage", 
    "tabs", 
    "webRequest", 
    "webRequestBlocking", 
    "cookies", 
    "bookmarks"
]
}
```

Comment: Don't use meta tag and redirect manually in newtab.js that is referenced in html via script tag. There are many examples you can find by googling.

Comment: P.S. I didn't post an answer because I'm afraid your main question is about getting the user id. Currently it may be dupe-closed to [Chrome extension to redirect tab to my page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21656100)